# xarray.Dataset.polyfit not available in xarray v 0.15.1

Tags: version, python-xarray

I am new to python. I updated xarray to 0.15.1 in order to use the new xarray.Dataset.polyfit and xarray.Dataset.polyval function. However these function are not available in my version. What am I doing wrong?

```
import xarray as xr
xr.__version__
```

Output is: `'0.15.1'`

```
xr.Dataset.polyfit?
```

Output is: `Object 'xr.dataset.polyfit' not found.`

Thank you!

Comment: I think your problem is that `.polyfit()` is a method which you apply to a Dataset, not just something you can call with `xr.Dataset.polyfit`. Try opening a basic dataset, ie. `ds=xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")` and then using `ds.polyfit()` on that, just to see if it's actually there

Comment: I already tried this, but it is not there.

Comment: What is the output when you try `ds.polyfit()` ? These questions are easier to answer when some details are provided :)

Comment: Sorry for that. The outut is ''Dataset' object has no attribute 'polyfit''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

polyfit is not released yet in xarray 0.15.1. See
[this xarray github issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3902) for more details.